# Raspberry pi - Could not find QuickTime, please reinstall Quicktime 7 or later

Tags: processing, raspberry-pi, quicktime

Can anyone help me on this please. I am running processing on my raspberry pi and I run the getting Started Video script from the examples. I have connected a logitech C910 on the raspberry PI. I am also running it through VNC on my mac. Here is the script:

```
import processing.video.*;
Capture Cam;

void setup(){
  size (320, 240);
  cam = new Capture(this, 320, 240);
}

void draw(){
  if (cam.available() == true) {
  cam.read();
   image(cam, 160, 100);
  }
 }
```

Here is the error:
Exception in thread Änimation Thread
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: quicktime/std/stdQTExcepption
...
...
...

If anyone knows how to solve this problem please help.

THanks a lot.

Comment: George's comment below about using oF, while much more complicated, is probably the better option in the long run. But if you're dead set on using Processing, poke around about using the GStreamer libraries on Linux, as you can't use Quicktime afaik

Answer (score 2):

I've tried Processing on a model B Raspberry PI but it ran too slow.

Although initial compilation is slow, at this point in time, I've but much better results
using openframeworks and the video grabber it provides.
Please try using [openframeworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-Getting-Started.html) and the grabber example.